# Does __global__ have overhead over __device__?

Tags: c++, performance, cuda, gpu

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373940/difference-between-global-and-device-functions) asks the difference between `__device__` and `__global__`.

The difference is:

> `__device__` functions can be called only from the device, and it is executed only in the device.
>
> `__global__` functions can be called from the host, and it is executed in the device.

I interpret the difference between `__global__` and `__device__` to be similar to `public` and `private` class access specifiers. The point is to prevent accidentally calling a `__device__` function from the host. It sounds like I could tag all `void`-returning functions as `__global__` without changing program behavior. Would this change program performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `__global__` has overhead, compared to `__device__`, but there are additional details to be aware of.  What you're proposing probably isn't a good idea.

`__global__` is the device code *entrypoint*, from host code.  Initially, the GPU has no code running on it.  When your host code decides that it wants to start some processing on the GPU, this can *only* be done by calling a `__global__` function (that is the so-called *kernel launch*).

You can call a `__global__` function from device code, but that is invoking something called [CUDA Dynamic Parallelism](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism) which has all the attributes of a kernel launch.   If you're a beginner, you almost certainly don't want to do that.

If you have code running on the GPU, and you want to call a function in the context of a CUDA thread, the way to do that is by calling a `__device__` function.

> It sounds like I could tag all void-returning functions as `__global__` without changing program behavior. Would this change program performance?

It would change both behavior and performance.

When you call a `__global__` function (whether from host code or device code) the only way to do that is via a properly configured kernel launch.  Using the typical method in the CUDA runtime API, that would be:

```
kernel<<<blocks, threads, ...>>>(... arguments ...);
```

That stuff in the triple-chevron syntax makes it different from an ordinary function call, and it will behave differently.  It will launch a new kernel, with its own grid  (the complement of threads/blocks associated with a kernel launch).

When you call a `__device__` function, it looks like an ordinary function call:

```
func(... arguments ...);
```

and behaves like one also.  It operates within the context of single thread, and does not spin up any new threads/blocks/kernel to service the function call.

You might want to spend a few hours in an [orderly introduction](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/) to the topic.  Just a suggestion, do as you wish of course.